# How to randomly select within a column category in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How do you randomly select certain number of rows per column value? I looked at other articles, which did not provide solutions (e.g., suggested to get 5 random selection from all rows, not for each column value).

For instance, I have a MySQL database of a forum, where columns include thread id, reply id (the replies to the thread initiating post), and poster id. I want to randomly select 4 thread initiating posts from each poster.

Comment: Sorry, you need to select 4 random threads for each poster? it means, rows that are not a reply?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you table name is "thread" maybe something like this should work

> SELECT * FROM thread ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;

I don't know how efficient is this but probably with large tables is not very recommended. Maybe generate random number in PHP or other language is a better option.